# Can't initialize WebWorker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-worker, voice-recording

I am trying to record voice in browser with the help of code at [GitHub link to VoicePin Code](https://github.com/VoicePIN/voicepin-recording-web)

and it seems the worker.postMessage in recorder.js is working but there is no worker thread receiving it. I setup the recorder.js to log messages from all its methods and i see methods up to the time i try to get messages from getBuffers method. After this method is called, the recorderWorker based WebWorker has to callback the callBack method we pass. That is where i see nothing in logs. When i examine code, the recorderWorker.js starts sending back data with onmessage() 
call for the first time with that callback.

From this, i think the recorderWoker.js is never initialized because the location i give in both recorder.js and audioManager.js is wrong.

Here is my code..

In my page i load the three js files as...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%@include file="../scripts/voicepin/recorder.js" %>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%@include file="../scripts/voicepin/recorderWorker.js" %>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%@include file="../scripts/voicepin/audiomanager.js" %>
</script>
```

The following are the two alternative ways i tried to pass on recorder worker's path...

```
var recorderWorkerPath = 'recorderWorker.js';
```

alternatively ...

```
var recorderWorkerPath = 'scripts/voicepin/recorderWorker.js';
```

The folder scripts is under WEB-INF

Looks like i did not learn anything with passing on file location information properly in web pages. Can someone help?

Comment: No one? Or did I add information in confusing way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple mistake  of putting the javaScript files under WEB-INF instead of WebContent. Changing to right position solved it.